# $X^2$ irreducible but not prime

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

> Let $K$ be a field. I'd like to show that in $R=\{\sum a_i X^i\in K[X]\mid a_1=0\}$, the element $X^2$ is irreducible, but not prime.

Irreducibility is checked easily, but I can't see why it's not prime.

$X^2$ divides every polynomial with constant term $= 0$, but none of the nonzero ones. Thus, I have to multiply 2 polynomials with constant nonzero terms, but then the resulting polynomial also has constant term which isn't zero, so $X^2$ doesn't divide it?

Comment: "$X^2$ divides every polynomial with constant term $= 0$" -- this is not true, $X^2$ does not divide $X^3$ (in $R$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\  X^2\mid\, X^3\cdot X^3,\:$ but $\, X^2\nmid X^3\,$ since $\,X^3/X^2 = X\not\in R$